# Better way to include images in AS3 than embed?

Tags: actionscript-3, image, actionscript, embed, flixel

I am putting together a Flash game (using Flixel) and I have a lot of sprites whose images (.png format, mostly) I need to include in my game. I'm used to using code like:

```
[Embed(source = "../../lib/ship-0001.png")]private var _ship0001Sprite:Class;
```

in order to include an image file. Is there a way I can do this other than embed? I'd like to use a for loop if possible, grabbing every needed file by number. This way instead if having several lines for each ship type (to grab its sprite, icon, store view, etc), I can just change a variable (eg NUM_SHIP_TYPES) and add the files by number for the new ship.

Is embed the only way to do this where the files are included in the .swf, or is there another way I can do this? Or is there a way I can use a for loop *with* embed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not be a popular answer. But it depends on preferences. **`I'm not trying to start a best practices discussion, just listing a possibility.`**

If you have multiple images for each ship. And its the same number of images per each ships then the below could be a possibility. Of not, then completely ignore what I suggest.

Have a folder for each one of your ship types and then a class file within that folder and place your images within that folder along side the class files..

```
package shipimages.ship1 { class Ship1Images {
    [Embed(source="0001.png")] public var img0001:Class;
    [Embed(source="0002.png")] public var img0002:Class;
    [Embed(source="0003.png")] public var img0003:Class;
} }
```

.

```
package shipimages.ship2 { class Ship2Images {
    [Embed(source="0001.png")] public var img0001:Class;
    [Embed(source="0002.png")] public var img0002:Class;
    [Embed(source="0003.png")] public var img0003:Class;
} }
```

But as I said, this is only beneficial in a small case scenarios but it does mean everything is more sub divided and if you were to make an Interface it could be easily done for factory pattern.

Comment: That is actually a good idea, though you're probably right that it's not a best practice. If I do it this way, every ship type will have its own folder, and everything for that ship type will be in that folder.

Thanks!

Comment: These class files can be generated automatically by a simple script or a tool, which just changes the numbers in filenames and substitutes them to a predefined pattern.

Answer (score 5):

If you have lots of assets, the best way is to leave them as external files and use `Loader` to load them.

That way you can display a progress bar and, as you said, it also makes it easier to manage your assets.

Comment: Do you mean [`Loader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have the objects readily available within the same swf or do you want to load them externally. Would be the first question, that comes to my mind.

- If you want to embedd images inside the swf : Add them all in an fla, create a swc from it and use them in your project. When you want to change something, change the fla. Regenerate the swc. Recompile.
- If you want the images to be loaded on runtime, use UrlLoader, personally I prefer using LoaderMax, which is part of the greensock package. It gives you more options to work with loading. Here is an example to help you out : http://www.greensock.com/loadermax-tips/